# Use "/dev/urandom" with GMP library to generate a very big random number

Tags: c, cryptography, entropy

I'm using Debian Bookworm and GMP library version 60201.
I need to generate a random number with GMP library but I have 2 requirements, if possible, of course!

1 - Generate a number between 0 and a specific max value.

2 - Have some kind of entropy, preferrably from "/dev/urandom/" or anything better, but not too much complciated.

I have never worked with this library and I don't have any experience working with big numbers or cryptography, so, I've been trying to look at the docs, examples in the internet and even AI tools, but so far, I couldn't understand at least about the second point.
I don't know if it is possible to use "/dev/urandom/" to get entropy or even if it is possible to add entropy using GMP library!

For the 1st point, I may have a solution, which is to generate random numbers while the generated number is not below the target max value. Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but seems to be a way!

Something like this:

```c
do{
    /* 
     code to generate a random number
    */
}while(randNumber > max_target_val);
```

For the second point, I see this in the docs:
https://gmplib.org/manual/Random-State-Seeding

> On some systems there’s a special device /dev/random which provides random data better suited for use as a seed.

But I can't find any suitable example on how to use "/dev/urandom/" with GMP library.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And `mpz_urandomm()`

Comment: I know I could use those but I wanted to learn how to add entropy or at least get a "better" random number by using "/dev/urandom" or even "/dev/random".

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate numbers as seeds using /dev/urandom, the following code can assist you.

```c
uint64_t random_num() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("/dev/urandom", "rb");
    uint64_t num = 0;
    fread(&num, sizeof(uint64_t), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Just `getrandom(&num, sizeof(num), 0)`. No need to open/close files.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Because I am currently using macOS, the standard library does not have the `getrandom` function.

Comment: Use arc4random on Mac. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/arc4random.3.html  (This is the highest quality random number source on Mac. Do not fret over "RC4." Its name is historical. The current implementation uses AES. It's the same source as /dev/random.)